# City centre of Lucerne in Google map

Tags: switzerland, maps, lucerne

I am struggling to find the city centre of Lucerne, Switzerland in Google maps, and how far is it from Lucerne rail station. I cannot spot the city centre of Lucerne in Google maps.  Actually I am searching for budget hotels very close to city centre. It will be very helpful if someone spots the city centre in google map, so that I can search for hotels near it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lucerne has an old city and a new city part, split by the river running through it. On [this map](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Karte_Luzern_Stadtkreise_2012.png), you can see the pink "Altstadt" (=old city) where the river ends in the lake, at the centre. The main train station is just south-east of that, across the river.

I would consider the Altstadt the center of the city, others might consider one of the bridges the center, or the roads along the river just before the lake starts. In any case, I would take a look at the size of the city. It's not very large and if you are willing to walk a couple of hundred meters from the hotel to the station, you will find out that you will not have a considerable distance from any of the points mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

On google maps, [this point](https://maps.google.ch/maps?q=47.052311,8.305984&num=1&t=m&z=17) for instance is in the old town/city centre.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I don't quite agree. abc requested to locate the city center on google maps, which is what I did. I don't see the point in restating everything that uncovery has already correctly stated in his answer when all that's lacking is the google maps link that was requested for.

Comment: The only thing you did is providing a point in the city center on google maps. The question is about locating the city center, not a point. Your answer is useless without @uncovery answer, so this is a comment on his post. Plus, on a personal point of view, his answer contains a full paragraph about why a point in google maps would not mean anything.

Comment: +1 from me. Nuances and details are good and city centre is always tricky to define but this answer is certainly useful and seems to address the question directly.

Comment: @Annoyed Vince's comment was on the unedited version.